# The 3 Treasures

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Oras, a great sailor, accidentally docked on a deserted island. He checked his compass and it is not working as it rotates in all direction. He boarded off to investigate the island and saw a cave. Inside the cave, he found 3 treasure boxes with locks. It seems it needs number combinations for it to unlock.

As he checked further, he saw a piece of parchment with a note. It says: "Time is running out for me. For whoever find these treasures, you can find the answer here. Find your way and you will see it."

[image]

There are 3 treasures:

**Roman treasure**

> needs 3 digits to unlock

**Japanese treasure**

> needs 2 digits to unlock

**Pirate treasure**

> needs 2 digits to unlock

HINT:

> solving the codes/digits for each treasure is somehow different from one another

HINT 2:

> methods/techniques can be reused but see it in a different aspect. Results from Roman is different from Japanese and Pirate. Also for one of the solution, clock technique is not mixed with other technique. Numbers that you will meet using the other technique are there for a reason.

HINT 3:

> Roman - visual, Japanese - not, Pirate - not; 2 clock techniques and 1 other technique. "ADD" is there for a reason when you meet it using a technique. Pirate is harder I think. Pirates do not use Clocks when navigating.

HINT 4: (Chinese New Year Hint)

> Pirate is Black Arrow. Again, "Pirates do not use Clocks when navigating". Combine with Hint 2's "Numbers that you will meet using the other technique are there for a reason". For Japanese, Roman technique with a twist and use Hint 2 also.

- Will reveal answer after bounty expires :)

CHATROOM:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35150/the-3-treasures

Comment: Just to clarify, since the grid contains several 2-digit numbers:  are the codes in fact 3, 2, and 2 *digits* or could it be something like `12-24-16` (three numbers, but six digits)?

Comment: my replies are in the chatroom :)

Comment: Add a note that if you make a mistake even once you will die, to prevent getting answers like "At worst you need to try 1000+100+100 combinations. With one combination per second it will take..."

Comment: So is there any answer available yet?

Comment: hmmm, thinking will add more clues. I think, some are close in solving the last one. see chatroom

Comment: @Mekalikot I think the reason this has been unanswered for so long is that there's no real way to know that you've gotten the correct answer for the Japanese or Pirate treasures. The Roman is quite clever, and as soon as you figure it out, there's an Aha! moment. But I don't see how that could happen with the other two.  Perhaps add some condition that will allow puzzlers to have that moment with the other two treasures.

Comment: @DanRussell sorry about that, I changed other way of solving the other two to avoid being obvious.. will improve future puzzzles :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spend some time wayfinding, then unlock the treasures with the following codes:

---

**Roman Treasure:**

> 9 0 0

Because:

> As @Alconja said in chat: "Starts with the blue arrow and is inspired by this puzzle: [The Sands of Time](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11913/the-sands-of-time)
>  Produces the letters CM (or 900 in Roman Numerals)" and further demonstrated:
>  [image]
>  Thanks Alconja.

---

**Japanese Treasure:**

> 4 2

Because:

> Using the clock-method I begin at the red arrow (since blue was Roman and it is said pirate is black) and navigate through some numbers, only to arrive at "ADD". Considering the numbers have meaning, as does the instruction to add, I go back to find my way, adding the numbers as I go...
>  10 + 1 + 16 + 1 + 14 = 42

---

**Pirate Treasure:**

> 2 0 (or 3 5)

Because:

> Starting at the black arrow and using each cardinal direction letter as an instruction, I run into East twice, taking me to 8. At that point, I look around and find a path leading South, which leads me to 12 where the trail seems to end. Looking around again, I see the clearest trail is to the East. Following that, I then find a trail, where I think Roman's have been. Following it, I head south and encounter an instruction... A - D - D (- 1 - 5). At that point I hit the coast, and think, perhaps this is a clue the pirates setup as they wandered...
>  I'll add 8 + 12, the #s I encountered before "ADD", to get 20. If that doesn't work, I'll add 15 more as the # I found after "ADD", getting 35. I head back to the pirate's chest to try it...

Comment: You are close to solving Pirate. For Pirate, it's like the Roman on how you move (1 step) then like Japanese solution,get the numbers and follow the cardinal directions and you'll end up with the same like the Japanese.

Comment: @Mekalikot I gave the Pirate Treasure another try and updated this answer

Comment: let me try again, follow the cardinal directions. starting with E(east a step) then another E, then you will get the number. Then what cardinal direction surrounding that number?(hint S) then follow again to get number then another cardinal direction then you will see ADD...

Comment: @Mekalikot sorry to make you spell it out. Jumping to *what cardinal direction surrounded that number* didn't feel right to me at first, but in retrospect that's what the *compass spinning in every direction* clue was about eh?

Comment: yup, correct with 35, it's 8+12 ADD 15. Other surrounding letters does not make any sense, only E and S will direct you if you are using the compass :)